# How to compare two columns in two different excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to link my products listed on the products sheet with their correspondent images listed on the images sheet to get the results on a new sheet named sheet3.

For instance, I have this:

**products sheet :**

```
Product ID     
10666      
10099      
5858
```

**images sheet :**

```
Image ID    Image Url      
10666       http://img.mysite.com/images/AB25.jpg      
10094       http://img.mysite.com/images/80.jpg    
10095       http://img.mysite.com/images/51.jpg    
10099       http://img.mysite.com/images/5a.jpg    
9765        http://img.mysite.com/images/7c.jpg    
9765        http://img.mysite.com/images/b.jpg     
9766        http://img.mysite.com/images/e6.jpg    
9767        http://img.mysite.com/images/bb.jpg    
5858        http://img.mysite.com/66.jpg       
5858        http://img.mysite.com/77.jpg
```

**What I want is sheet3 that shows me this:**

```
Image ID    Image Url      
10666       http://img.mysite.com/images/AB25.jpg      
10099       http://img.mysite.com/images/5a.jpg    
5858        http://img.mysite.com/66.jpg       
5858        http://img.mysite.com/77.jpg
```

Thanks

Comment: check out VLOOKUP function

Comment: VLOOKUP(products!A2,images!A:B,2,FALSE) is working with me, however it just shows one single image for each product, this is why I need help here

Comment: What's the difference between images sheet and sheet3

Comment: sheet3 shows only images of products listed in products sheet

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need vba but anyway try this:

```
Sub HTH()

    shtProducts.UsedRange.Resize(, 1).Copy Sheet3.Range("A1")

    With Sheet3.Range("A2", Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Images!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Sub HTH()

   Worksheets("images").UsedRange.Resize(, 1).Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1")

    With Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A2", Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
        .Formula = "=MATCH(A2,products!$A:$A,0)"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
        .ClearContents
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time Error 424: Object Required?

Comment: On which line? You have to replace shtproducts and sheet3 with your actual sheet codenames. Or if you dont use codenames replace with `worksheets("products")`

Comment: It is working after replacing all sheets names with Sheets("sheet_name"), however the final result was again showing one single image for each product :       
10666 http://img.mysite.com/images/AB25.jpg      
10099 http://img.mysite.com/images/5a.jpg    
5858 http://img.mysite.com/66.jpg

Comment: Ok, well I'm not surprised you have three close votes for your question.  Its not very clear.  Try the code I added.